# Adding to a value declared in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is hard to explain, you can see a **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/xntn7p5p/4/)**

I have a products table that dynamically creates/deletes new lines of products. I also have a totals table that totals up the totals of each line together.

In that totals box, I have a travel box I want to add to the grand total, but the issue I am having is the travel input is outside the table that is totaling all the values. I can replace the total with a new total, but I can not seem to call the sub total, add the travel and output a grand total.

**HTML**

```
<table class="order-details">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="Work Description" class="wei-add-field description 1"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="QTY" class="wei-add-field quantity 1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="$0.00" class="wei-add-field unit-price 1"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="$0.00" class="wei-add-field price-total 1" id=""/></td>
        <td> </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="wei-add-service"><a href="#" class="button-secondary wei-add-service-button">Add Item</a></div>

<table class="wei-add-totals">
    <tr>
        <td width="50%">Sub Total</td>
        <td width="50%" class="wie-add-subtotal"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="alternate travel">
        <td>Travel</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="0.00" class="wei-add-field travel" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Taxes</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="0.00" class="wei-add-field wie-total-taxes" id="wei-disabled" disabled/> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alternate total">
        <td>Total</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="" placeholder="0.00" class="wei-add-field wie-grand-total" id="wei-disabled" disabled/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
var counter = 1;
var testArray =  [ 2,3,4,5];

jQuery('a.wei-add-service-button').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" class="wei-add-field description ' + counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" class="wei-add-field quantity ' + counter + '" /></td><td><input type="text" class="wei-add-field unit-price ' + counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="$0.00" class="wei-add-field price-total ' + counter + '" id=""/></td><td><a href="#">X</a></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.order-details').append(newRow);
});


jQuery('table.order-details').on('click','tr a',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var table = $(this).closest('table');
    jQuery(this).parents('tr').remove();
    reCalculate.call( table );
});


jQuery('table.order-details').on("keyup", "tr", reCalculate);

function reCalculate() {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    jQuery(this).closest('table').find('tr').each(function() {
        var row = jQuery(this);
        var value = +jQuery( ".unit-price", row ).val();
        var value2 = +jQuery( ".quantity", row ).val();
        var total = value * value2;
        grandTotal += total;
        jQuery( ".wei-add-field.price-total", row ).val( '$' + total.toFixed(2) );
    });
    jQuery(".wie-add-subtotal").text( '$' + grandTotal.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: Your DEMO and your code in this question *don't match*.  Use `jQuery(".wie-add-subtotal").text` instead of `jQuery(".wie-add-subtotal").val`, since `.wie-add-subtotal` is not an `input` field.

Comment: Where's that shipping input?

Comment: The shipping... I am sorry it is called travel. And the subtotal correctly ads everything I have, I am just not sure how to also add the "Travel" into the total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think, given the task of creating this, I would have chosen to do it in the way you did.

However, using your existing code you can bind the Travel value on change, paste, or keyup and run a function on any of those actions. Within that function I have removed the special character ($) from ".wie-grand-total" using a regex and converted the value of ".wie-grand-total" to a float using parseFloat. I also converted the Travel value to a float using parseFloat. I then added them together and made the sum your new value for "wie-grand-total".

```
/* NEW SINCE COMMENTS */

//Add to your HTML New table

<table class="order-details">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="Work Description" class="wei-add-field description 1"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="QTY" class="wei-add-field quantity 1" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="$0.00" class="wei-add-field unit-price 1"/></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="" name="" placeholder="$0.00" class="wei-add-field price-total 1" id=""/></td>

      /* NEW SINCE COMMENTS*/
      <td><input type="text" id="travelHid" value=""></td>

      <td> </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



/* NEW SINCE COMMENTS */

$('#travelHid').hide();
var travelVal = 0;
function updateTravelVal(travelVal){
     var  travelVal = travelVal;
     $('#travelHid').val(travelVal);
};
updateTravelVal();


$("#travelVis").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
    var noChars = jQuery(".wie-grand-total").val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    var newTot = parseFloat(noChars) + parseFloat($(this).val());
    jQuery(".wie-grand-total").val( '$' + newTot.toFixed(2));


     //added error checking
     var checkError = jQuery(".wie-grand-total").val( '$' + newTot.toFixed(2));

      //if the value that would go in input is NaN then use travelVal
      //since there is no value in .wie-grand-total yet
        if (typeof checkError !== "string") {
          jQuery(".wie-grand-total").val( '$' + travelVal.toFixed(2))
        } else if (typeof checkError === "string") {
         jQuery(".wie-grand-total").val( '$' + newTot.toFixed(2))   
        } 

      /* NEW SINCE COMMENTS */

      updateTravelVal(travelVal);
});
```

A fiddle for demonstration (now with hiddenVal per comment)
http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/wed6eog0/3/

Only potential problems here are it only runs when you change, paste, or key up the value in #TravelVis.

/*EXPLAINED SINCE COMMENTS*/

It the html I added a td with input. Input id="travelHid". I then make that invisible by applying jQuery method .hide(). I then exposed travelVal to global scope an initiated it with a value of zero then created a function to update that value.

Within that function I set the value to the argument travelVal or to 0 if there are no args. I then immediately call it.

Then, I added a call to that function with the arg travelVal from our bind function to update it if a value is present.

And finally:

Just add a row to the table with preset value of Travel and Quant 1.

http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/xntn7p5p/5/

Comment: `"input"` (`oninput` event) is the short of `"change paste keyup"`

Comment: The issue now is that when a value is changed or removed from the product table, it does not add the travel into it... maybe this is why you would have done it differently. Is there a better way to do it (unless its too hard to explain) or a way to keep the shipping added when changing the product data?

Comment: you could add a hidden td in the rows and bind it to your total value then use that value when calculating your new total

Comment: @BrandonTurpy I would just add a button that says "add travel" and have it create a row which allows you to enter a travel value